# Indic language support in android SDK

Tags: android, internationalization

I am creating an android app using the phonegap. So i can use HTML for creating the application. It is working fine. My problem is when I use Indic text in my page, it is not showing in the android emulator. I am using the latest version, that is SDK 4 . How to make it display the Indic text correctly...? As I am using Phone gap does, the embedding of fonts will work and if so where should I put the embed code..?

I am also planning to load the contnt from a web-server as JSON or in any other format. That is also in the Indic format. So is this possible...?

Comment: From what I know, it is not possible. The Android fonts don't have glyphs for any Indic scripts, and the text engine will not know how to handle the shaping even if you use your own font.

Comment: Thanks Mihai. But I have seen some of the apps displaying indic language text in phones. Do you know how they are doing it. ?